# Add-in For 'Off the grid' customer

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-js-helpers

I have developed an add-in for our company which basically loads part of our app into an iframe. This is fine, But we have a governmental customer whos users are essentially off the grid ie no outside internet access, The web-app portion of the add-in is hosted on the internal web servers within the building but I am having trouble loading the add-in in their powerpoint app? is this due to having no internet access?

I'm aware that the manifest has a required link to schemas, for example: xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"

would this be the cause of the problem? and if so is there a workaround? ie hosting the schemas locally

TIA

Comment: How is the add-in manifest deployed? Is it in a network share? Also, please provide more details about "trouble loading the add-in". What are the steps that lead to the problem? Is there an error message associated with the problem?

Comment: so just at the moment the manifest was on a shared folder on a users computer. Essentially the add-in just isnt loading within the window when its inserted into the document, it tries to load and fails after a few seconds, if i remember correctly i think the error was something along the lines of cant be reached or cant be loaded or something vague anyway(thats even more vague, i know, sorry). The users f12 was disabled for some reason so i couldnt use that.

Comment: Well, please get the exact error message, because "can't be reached" and "can't be loaded" aren't quite the same thing. Also, if the user pastes the add-in's URL in a browser, does the page open?

Comment: Yeah, they can access the add in, as I have some assets and they were able to open those. I'v never been able to open my add-ins in the browser, not sure why, I get a warning in the console thats its being open outside the office environment(and this user had no F12 so i couldnt test)